# "Unboundlocalerror: Local Variable "Val" Referenced before Assignment" Error

Tags: python-2.7, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get my script to loop in such a way that it will load the outputs in 1 file, and then when it's done loading everything move the values to output file 2 , erase the values in output file 1 and start reloading them, then when those are down move the values into output two (overwriting the old ones) repeat.

I have been pretty successful so far and don't know what else to add to my script and am hoping someone here knows why I keep getting ""Unboundlocalerror: Local Variable "Val" Referenced before Assignment" error randomly midway through the loading process, when I have a very small input file, the script performs how I want.

Does anyone know how I can change my script to fix that error, I have tried to understand why it is happening but cannot.

I have tried to research it thoroughly but none of the suggestions I have found have worked (or I implemented them incorrectly, I have attached my script. Thanks!

```
    import urllib2,re,urllib,urlparse,csv,sys,time,threading,codecs,shutil
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    def extract(url):
        try:
            sys.stdout.write('0')
            # global file
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

            product = soup.find("div", {"class": "js-product-price"})
            price = product.findNext('div',{'class': 'js-price-display'}).getText().strip()
            oos = product.findNext('p', attrs={'class': "price-oos"})

            if oos is None:
                oos = 'In Stock'
            else:
                oos = oos.getText()

            val = url + "," + price + "," + oos + "," + time.ctime() + '\n'
            # ifile.write(val)
            sys.stdout.write('1')
        except Exception as e:
            print e

        return val

    while True:
        ifile = open('output.csv', "w", 0)
        inputs = csv.reader(open('input.csv'))
        # inputs = csv.reader(codecs.open('input.csv', 'rU', 'utf-16'))

        ifile.write('URL' + "," + 'Price' + "," + 'Stock' + "," + "Time" + '\n')

        for i in inputs:
            ifile.write(extract(i[0]))
        ifile.close()
```

Update:

Thanks for the help guys! This is my new script:

```
import urllib2,re,urllib,urlparse,csv,sys,time,threading,codecs,shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def extract(url):
    try:
        sys.stdout.write('0')
        # global file
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        product = soup.find("div", {"class": "js-product-price"})
        price = product.findNext('div',{'class': 'js-price-display'}).getText().strip()
        oos = product.findNext('p', attrs={'class': "price-oos"})

        if oos is None:
            oos = 'In Stock'
        else:
            oos = oos.getText()

        val = url + "," + price + "," + oos + "," + time.ctime() + '\n'
        # ifile.write(val)
        sys.stdout.write('1')
    except Exception as e:
        print e

    else:
        return val

while True:
    ifile = open('output.csv', "w", 0)
    inputs = csv.reader(open('input.csv'))
    # inputs = csv.reader(codecs.open('input.csv', 'rU', 'utf-16'))

    ifile.write('URL' + "," + 'Price' + "," + 'Stock' + "," + "Time" + '\n')

    for i in inputs:
        val_to_write = extract(i[0])
        if val_to_write:
            ifile.write(val_to_write)
        ifile.close()

    shutil.copy('output.csv', 'output2.csv')

print("finished")
```

With the above script I am now getting the error: "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `try-except-else` as you would only want to `return val` if no exception was raised (if an exception was raised then `val` wouldn't be assigned to when you try to `return` it). Another suggestion is not to use a "catch-em-all" `except` block.

```
def extract(url):
    try:
        sys.stdout.write('0')
        # global file
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        product = soup.find("div", {"class": "js-product-price"})
        price = product.findNext('div',{'class': 'js-price-display'}).getText().strip()
        oos = product.findNext('p', attrs={'class': "price-oos"})

        if oos is None:
            oos = 'In Stock'
        else:
            oos = oos.getText()

        val = url + "," + price + "," + oos + "," + time.ctime() + '\n'
        # ifile.write(val)
        sys.stdout.write('1')
    except Exception as e:
        print e

    else:
        return val
```

But be warned: if an exception does occur then `extract` will return `None` and the calling code will have to take account for that, for example:

```
for i in inputs:
    val_to_write = extract(i[0])
    if val_to_write:
        ifile.write(val_to_write)
    ifile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!! I am trying it right now. I have been working on this for ages. Much appreciated

Comment: Hey, So I gave it a whirl and now I am getting "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" after loading 1 or 2 things -- any ideas?

Comment: Don't `open` and `close` the file inside the `while True` loop.

Comment: I feel so silly to ask this but when I try deleting the open line under while true in my script wouldn't that cause it to not function properly?

Comment: I have attached the script I am using now. Not sure how to edit it according to what you said

Comment: It gives me "Ifile not defined" when I delete the open and close lines under while true

Comment: To be precise it gives me "NameError: name "Ifile" is not defined"